# How can I connect the mayanedms API to my Django project?

Tags: django, docker, mayanedms

I would like to connect MayanEdms API to my Django project.

Note that Mayan is running on different port from my Django container (both are running Docker).

The problem I'm having is because, if I navigate to the API link, it works for me, but if I do it through code it doesn't. I don't know why that is?

I attach below the error that I get both in the browser and in the command console. I also attach the function that should connect to the API.

What I want this function to do is to list all the documents that arrive to my email (it is read with MayanEdms). Once the documents are saved in Mayan, I want to show the information of the emails, including the attached files, in the independent interface that I have made with django.

views.py:

```
@login_required  
def f_facturaspendientes(request):
    # URL de tu API externa que proporciona las facturas pendientes
    api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/documents/'

    # Datos de autenticación
    auth = ('admin', 'jehK4XvBGp')

    # Realiza una solicitud GET a la API con autenticación
    response = requests.get(api_url, auth=auth)

    # Verifica si la solicitud fue exitosa
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()  # Convierte la respuesta JSON en un diccionario de Python

        # Filtrar los documentos que contengan la etiqueta con el nombre de usuario
        user_documents = [doc for doc in data if request.user.first_name in doc['etiquetas']]

        return render(request, 'facturas_pendientes.html', {'user_documents': user_documents})
    else:
        # Manejo de errores, por ejemplo, mostrar un mensaje de error
        return render(request, 'error_template.html')
```

CLI:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapper_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/beleroforms_app/views.py", line 55, in f_facturaspendientes
    response = requests.get(api_url, auth=auth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/documents/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5ec9c04fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[04/Sep/2023 09:09:16] "GET /facturaspendientes/ HTTP/1.1" 500 170828
```

Browser:

```
ConnectionError at /facturaspendientes/
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/documents/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5ec9c04fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/facturaspendientes/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/documents/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5ec9c04fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py, line 519, in send
Raised during:  beleroforms_app.views.f_facturaspendientes
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.16
Python Path:    
['/code',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 04 Sep 2023 09:09:16 +0000
```